# How to add a horizontal target line to an excel pivot chart WITH slicers?

Tags: excel, charts, slicers

I am trying to add a target line horizontally across across a column chart which I can do easily on a pivot chart but as soon as I filter fields the target line goes away. Is there any way to have the target line stay on the chart no matter what field I am pulling up?

I added a column with my target number and changed that chart type to "line", which works on a chart to show a horizontal line across the chart. When I filter fields it goes away and doesn't show at all on the chart.